# Javascript: using array.sort() on a specific array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array structured like this, for any existing index *i*:

```
myArray[i] = [anIndex, aValue]
```

For example, its contents can be as follows:

```
myArray[0] = [2, 35]
myArray[1] = [3, 57]
myArray[2] = [5, 12]
myArray[3] = [6, 42]
```

I would like to sort this array in ascending order while keeping the same structure, and using *aValue* as the sorting parameter. In the case of the above example, I would get this result, for each index of the resulting sorted array:

- index 0: [5, 12]
- index 1: [2, 35]
- index 2: [6, 42]
- index 2: [3, 57]

I don't really understand how to achieve this using array.sort() - or if it's even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a `compareFunction`:

```js
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = [2, 35];
myArray[1] = [3, 57];
myArray[2] = [5, 12];
myArray[3] = [6, 42];

myArray = myArray.sort(function(x, y) {
  return x[1] - y[1];
});

console.log(myArray);
```